# How can I build a separation layer of protocols/interfaces between views and implementation?

Tags: swift, architecture, swift-protocols

I'm trying to separate the business logic, server API implementation and the presentation view from each other.
to do so I found the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles and MVVM design pattern very interesting.

**what I want to achieve is:**

to have a presentation module this would be dependent on a protocol module and then multiple implementation modules which are dependent on the protocol module or layer.

The app would have multiple services but to reduce the complexity I will explain what I tried regarding the authentication service as an example (other services are like object fetcher, sync ...)

In the separation layer of the protocol I have protocols only

```swift
protocol ServerConfiguration: Hashable, Codable {
    var baseURL: URL { get }
}

protocol Service: ObservableObject, Hashable, Codable {
    
    associatedtype Configuration: ServerConfiguration
    var configuration: Configuration { get }
    
    init(using configuration: Configuration)
    
    func performJob()
}

protocol AuthenticationService: Service {}
protocol TaskLoadingService: Service {}
```

And in the implementation module I write the implementation of these protocols as an example

```swift
struct SomeServerConfiguration: ServerConfiguration {
    var baseURL: URL
}

class SomeAuthenticationService: AuthenticationService {
    
    var configuration: Configuration
    
    required init(using configuration: SomeServerConfiguration) {
        self.configuration = configuration
    }
    
    func performJob() {}
}
```

My problem is whenever I try to reference the `Service` protocol the compiler complain because it uses Self and it has an associated type.
Now the solution for this was to try to create a type erasure and using something like AnyService which is a lot of work since there are many services with many different parameters.
I found some articles about type erasing for self but not for both self and associated types.

I would prefer not to use concrete types instead of protocol because that would lead to empty implementation with something like fatal error in them.

I'm looking for ideas to solve the generic protocol problem if you know any or on another way to implement this design pattern any example would be much appreciated. (maybe auto type erasing)

*I know this topic is very general but it would be great if the questions wasn't closed*

Comment: Once you go down the protocol with associate type route, you can't just refer to a protocol as a type. So, you really gotta ask yourself if you really need a protocol with associate type to begin with.

Comment: So would you suggest that for all the server configs like file certificate auth. Or basic auth username and password or another with a different method I would have to implement a path for that even though I know it will never be used

Comment: I think I can provide the details needed in the implementation initializer but still how about type erasing when only self is mentioned is there something like code gen?

Comment: I'm not really suggesting, because I don't know your situation. Why do you think it's difficult to type-erase `Service` - it only seems to have a single method.

Comment: I know what you mean but I still appreciate your ideas. the single method is as an example it will not be the only one

Comment: If you have the time, read this: https://robnapier.net/start-with-a-protocol as a way to calibrate your thinking about when and how to use protocols

Comment: Dave is a very amazing person